# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, ajax

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp3\htdocs\htdocsManagement\ecms.src\ecms.ajax\ajax.handle.readData.php
>   on line 8

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    require_once("../class.core.php");

    class ajaxReadData {
        private $mAnswer = array("isValid" => true);

        private $mType = $_POST["mType"];

        public function __construct() {
            global $workflowHandler;
            global $systemHandler;

            echo $this->mType;
            $this->getResult();
        }

        private function getResult() {
            echo json_encode($this->mAnswer);
        }
    } (new ajaxReadData());
?>
```

what is the error?

Comment: You can't assign "dynamic" values in the class definition. You have to move it in the constructor or in another method. (e.g. `$this->mType = ...`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `private $mType = $_POST["mType"];`

> This member declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a **constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

`$_POST["mType"]` is run-time information. Instead, move initialization to the constructor like so:

```
private $mType;

public function __construct() {
   global $workflowHandler;
   global $systemHandler;

   // Initialize with run-time data here
   $this->mType = $_POST["mType"];

   echo $this->mType;
   $this->getResult();
}
```